# How to add classes (e.g. lib) to a given Typo3 extension?

Tags: debugging, extension-methods, typo3

I got a (imho) minor noob question concerning writing of Typo3 Extensions (ver. 4.5 LTS). What I try is simply make up a little MVC class pattern which contains a small curl statement to retrieve information from a remote location. In principle, the MVC classes are already implemented and I just want to include them into the main procedure of my plugin extension. That was what I guessed to work:

```
class tx_uniklstudgangext2013_pi1 extends tslib_pibase {
public $prefixId      = 'tx_uniklstudgangext2013_pi1';      // Same as class name
public $scriptRelPath = 'pi1/class.tx_uniklstudgangext2013_pi1.php';    // Path to this script relative to the extension dir.
public $extKey        = 'uniklstudgangext2013'; // The extension key.
public $pi_checkCHash = TRUE;

/**
 * The main method of the Plugin.
 *
 * @param string $content The Plugin content
 * @param array $conf The Plugin configuration
 * @return string The content that is displayed on the website
 */
public function main($content, array $conf) {
    $this->conf = $conf;
    $this->pi_setPiVarDefaults();
    $this->pi_loadLL();

    $view = t3lib_div::makeInstance('tx_uniklstudgangext2013_pi1_view');
    // !HERE! : also tried with new(), since I don't want to deal with XCLASS here...
    // this works: $content = "<p>Hello world!</p>";...the line below doesn't...
    $content = $view->getCourseInfoOutput();
    /*'
        <strong>This is a few paragraphs:</strong><br />
        <p>This is line 1</p>
        <p>This is line 2</p>

        <h3>This is a form:</h3>
        <form action="' . $this->pi_getPageLink($GLOBALS['TSFE']->id) . '" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="' . $this->prefixId . '[input_field]" value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->piVars['input_field']) . '" />
            <input type="submit" name="' . $this->prefixId . '[submit_button]" value="' . htmlspecialchars($this->pi_getLL('submit_button_label')) . '" />
        </form>
        <br />
        <p>You can click here to ' . $this->pi_linkToPage('get to this page again', $GLOBALS['TSFE']->id) . '</p>
    ';
    */

    return $this->pi_wrapInBaseClass($content);
}
}
```

I am a beginner in the Typo3 programming and I guess there are a hundred implicit issues I don't have in mind so far (by just not knowing how Typo3 operates implicitly). What I tried/did so far:

- Disabling the template-cache globally by setting it up in the root template.
- Conversion of all new statements into makeInstance(); not wanting this hookup to screw all my MVC code, I overwrote the called method $view->getCourseInfoOutput() by

  ```
  public function getCourseInfoOutput() {
    return "hello world!";
    //return $this->_model->getTemplateByCourseId(5);
  }
  ```
- which leads me to the next issue: It just does not get the hello world within this! It seems, that Typo3 anyhow supresses the return value from  classes out of the extension root class
- When I put all the code successively into the main method, it worked out just fine

Could anyone please help me :/ I admit, that there is a slight possibility that I totally misunderstood how extensions work, but, as I said, I just want my code to run within the extension and simply return one single value. Is this really that hard?

Greetings & thx in advance!

Answer (score 1):

`$content` is any HTML string. If you created the extension with the kickstarter or used any existing extension as boilerplate, then you just have to care about what happens inside you function.
This totally depends on you. TYPO3 will create your class and will call the main method and use the return value as content.
You can find all relevant docs at http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ExtensionArchitecture/Index.html

You must of course **not** use any HTML inside your function. Your function must return the content as concatenate string with a return statement.

`TYPO3 CMS` uses `ob_clean` to flush the output buffer. If you forcefully output anything before `TYPO3 CMS` does, then you will break it.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that advice. This makes some things more clear to me, but the second issue with the MVC classes is still unclear to me. As one can see, I just want to return a "hello world!" and pass it to the $content variable, which does not work. For me, it looks like there is a supression on including "external" classes or invoking their code. The compiler anyway finds the method, but just not passes the returned value into the invoking main method.

Comment: If you use ``makeInstance``, then you have to stick to the ``TYPO3`` conventions, e.g. using one of the registered prefixes: ``Tx_,tx_,user_, etc``. Just use new if you do not want to relay on the TYPO3 magic. Make sure to ``include_once`` the other class before.